# CorruptZip error while Installing VS Code Azure Function Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to install the Azure Function Extension but I'm getting this error:

> 2023-08-14 15:14:10.370 [error] CorruptZip: end of central directory record signature not found
> at $t.download (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:141)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async ee.y (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:20021)
> at async ee.h (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:18112)
> 2023-08-14 15:14:10.474 [error] end of central directory record signature not found: CorruptZip: end of central directory record signature not found
> at $t.download (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:141)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async ee.y (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:20021)
> at async ee.h (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:18112)

I have VSCode version 1.81 installed.

I tried to install it using Extensions tab, and I tried to download it manually and installt with vsix.

Answer (score 1):

The above error indicates a problem with the central directory record signature within the downloaded zip file, which could be due to corruption during the download or an issue with the extension itself.

Follow this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows,portal,v2,bash&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to install **Azure Functions Core Tools** manually.

Here are the steps:

[image]

[image]

Click on install will install Azure Functions Core Tools to your PC.

[image]

Now, you can start installing **Azure Functions Core Tools** in **VS Code**. Follow the below steps:

Go to VS Code **Extensions**> **Azure Functions**> click on **Install** will install Azure Functions Core Tools in VS Code.

[image]

Comment: I have already installed the Azure Function Core Tools, but yet I'm still can't install the extension.

Comment: @Triple.B- Are you trying to install Azure functions like above in VS Code from Extension?

Comment: I tried form Extension and I tried to download the VSIX file and install it and both are giving me the same error

Comment: @Triple.B Sometimes, permission issues can cause problems during installation. Try running Visual Studio Code as an administrator and then attempt to install the extension again.